# Error while executing convert (imagemagick) in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to resize an image in windows. I have a shell script which I am executing using cygwin. Script is working fine. But I am unable to execute convert (imagmagick). I am getting the following error when I am executing the convert command.

`$ convert /cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Desktop/9121.JPG -resize 50% a.png

Error : convert.exe: unable to open image `/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Desktop/9121.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: no images defined`a.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set path variable to convert.exe path location, and then execute convert command